# Как взять данные из строки

Tags: python, строки, list

Есть вот такой список, в котором одна строка, в которой словарь, так вот как получить элементы от туда?

```
['{"cid":"s3kVtQRC","purl":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4YMwNqaqufc","murl":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/
MwNqaqufc/maxresdefault.jpg","turl":"https://tse2.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.s3kVtQRCMajM5sB7j-PpiAHaEK&pid=1
1","md5":"b37915b5044231a8cce6c07b8fe3e988","shkey":"3brE0hb1v3UUi+NuQ6X7wVMQL8nXEsijZFthVOevo8A=","t":"
nny Sneaky Cats - YouTube","mid":"152FEC4657AE253961A4508F4B5C72E7134C8355","desc":"sneaky cat cats anim
s funny kitty animal jooinn"}', '{"cid":"yx+UW2p6","purl":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H5t0orjZSFg",
url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/H5t0orjZSFg/maxresdefault.jpg","turl":"https://tse2.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.y
UW2p6XIuQz5xly6r0_gHaEK&pid=15.1","md5":"cb1f945b6a7a5c8b90cf9c65cbaaf4fe","shkey":"JLxjb1Um6vC1uyEhyYC0
ckTQosLqTr8AugdM5srmo=","t":"BLONDE CATS - YouTube","mid":"B7DA31AD238C5CCFC12960B81702C3059171986C","de
":"blonde cats"}', '{"cid":"+CEUDdFF","purl":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OAGfx7eB3gA","murl":"https
/i.ytimg.com/vi/OAGfx7eB3gA/maxresdefault.jpg","turl":"https://tse4.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.-CEUDdFFDZpoaW
zRiCHAHaEK&pid=15.1","md5":"f821140dd1450d9a68696a19cd18821c","shkey":"eJf7XbaPJsG3orhGnToxemxJeWzyF3EC5
eAq7Npqk=","t":"How to pick up a \ue000cat\ue001 like a pro - Vet advice on \ue000cat\ue001 ...","mid":"
AD782D503E4D9CA0CB8E78856E5ACBE21B07DE","desc":"cat vet advice handling pick"}', '{"cid":"i7j33APQ","pur
:"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat","murl":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4b/D
estic_Cat_Demonstrating_Dilated_Slit_Pupils.jpg/220px-Domestic_Cat_Demonstrating_Dilated_Slit_Pupils.jpg
"turl":"https://tse3.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.i7j33APQBvtlAYmJErPMhwAAAA&pid=15.1","md5":"8bb8f7dc03d006fb6
1898912b3cc87","shkey":"S3GTy2277E+KqJenmAcVhv6Ly7MfcU3XGbC1JAnHcO4=","t":"\ue000Cat\ue001 - Wikipedia",
id":"2B47BE55BDEDC04E0016DB8A5CDAB14D8CBE09A9","desc":"cat domestic dilated pupils wikipedia wiki slit w
ipediam"}', '{"cid":"+HbjTmpW","purl":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1TMEaKyE8pw","murl":"https://i.yt
g.com/vi/1TMEaKyE8pw/hqdefault.jpg","turl":"https://tse1.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.-HbjTmpWh0U7pBqnKxF2kQHaF
pid=15.1","md5":"f876e34e6a5687453ba41aa72b117691","shkey":"pdhXF7rFvEa2XxSjRk88q9Ef/2lgtwhlPmZRyTLhZKE=
"t":"Funny \ue000Cat\ue001 Bath 2013 - YouTube","mid":"A915348859EBF5E9DE540831ADF243181D363EC3","desc":
at bath funny"}', '{"cid":"mnvcW4H+","purl":"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ze8OmH_Zvlg","murl":"https:/
.ytimg.com/vi/ze8OmH_Zvlg/hqdefault.jpg","turl":"https://tse4.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.mnvcW4H-cqNVDLHmFlk7
HaFj&pid=15.1","md5":"9a7bdc5b81fe72a3550cb1e616593ba4","shkey":"/PLG95xACMCkubeFIv84yVFjBBcwAFyyQSkEJCO
xU=","t":"Munchkin \ue000Cat\ue001 Grooming Himself - YouTube","mid":"8BACF37B56EEF11DCCED8D5BBE9FC0077E
E4AC","desc":"cat munchkin grooming himself"}', '{"cid":"XULI4Paj","purl":"https://www.youtube.com/watch
=_NndSy2JR3c","murl":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/_NndSy2JR3c/maxresdefault.jpg","turl":"https://tse4.mm.bing
et/th?id=OIP.XULI4PajCI9VA48rj-O-UQHaEK&pid=15.1","md5":"5d42c8e0f6a3088f55038f2b8fe3be51","shkey":"q+XL
Sg/+XNn6xxPFVqNqx605W6/GnGatYTEbzP+dU=","t":"THE WOLF \ue000CAT\ue001 - The Lykoi - YouTube","mid":"97B4
9B549E6E80A7E67C867DDC5AD39AA9A5B8","desc":"lykoi cat wolf breed werewolf guy werewolves dodo hated scoo
r turns dad ultimate special animal"}', '{"cid":"prhbPpvf","purl":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somali_
t","murl":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c6/Blue_Somali_kitten_age_3_months.jpg
200px-Blue_Somali_kitten_age_3_months.jpg","turl":"https://tse3.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.prhbPpvfN4tlsqnheW
mQHaFj&pid=15.1","md5":"a6b85b3e9bdf378b65b2a9e179646199","shkey":"BT0hxF/DerB1g4mL7o6M2/KTGDBy6HiqCYh9w
47Gc=","t":"Somali \ue000cat\ue001 - Wikipedia","mid":"C7F9F1321500598998BDBA40C7C402E40752500A","desc":
omali wikipedia cat kitten wiki months"}', '{"cid":"o8LbSVIj","purl":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siam
e_cat","murl":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f6/Siamese_Cat_p.jpg/1200px-Siames
Cat_p.jpg","turl":"https://tse4.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.o8LbSVIjkCNCPEXeuvSu1gHaHl&pid=15.1","md5":"a3c2db
52239023423c45debaf4aed6","shkey":"NsZXfm7H/WsyPG7xZi7JS1eh3ZGqYjiCiClE/2IHbFI=","t":"Siamese \ue000cat\
001 - Wikipedia","mid":"1C5812CF7F9D820F828C775F7A182485E6E790FF","desc":"siamese cat wikipedia wiki"}']
```

как получить все элементы с ид 'murl' ?

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос метку языка программирования.

Comment: Что в итоге должно быть?

Answer (score 0):

решил:

```
import ast

urls = ['{"cid":"s3kVtQRC","purl":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4YMwNqaqufc","murl":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/
MwNqaqufc/maxresdefault.jpg","turl":"https://tse2.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.s3kVtQRCMajM5sB7j-PpiAHaEK&pid=1
1","md5":"b37915b5044231a8cce6c07b8fe3e988","shkey":"3brE0hb1v3UUi+NuQ6X7wVMQL8nXEsijZFthVOevo8A=","t":"
nny Sneaky Cats - YouTube","mid":"152FEC4657AE253961A4508F4B5C72E7134C8355","desc":"sneaky cat cats anim
s funny kitty animal jooinn"}', '{"cid":"yx+UW2p6","purl":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H5t0orjZSFg",
url":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/H5t0orjZSFg/maxresdefault.jpg","turl":"https://tse2.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.y
UW2p6XIuQz5xly6r0_gHaEK&pid=15.1","md5":"cb1f945b6a7a5c8b90cf9c65cbaaf4fe","shkey":"JLxjb1Um6vC1uyEhyYC0
ckTQosLqTr8AugdM5srmo=","t":"BLONDE CATS - YouTube","mid":"B7DA31AD238C5CCFC12960B81702C3059171986C","de
":"blonde cats"}', '{"cid":"+CEUDdFF","purl":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OAGfx7eB3gA","murl":"https
/i.ytimg.com/vi/OAGfx7eB3gA/maxresdefault.jpg","turl":"https://tse4.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.-CEUDdFFDZpoaW
zRiCHAHaEK&pid=15.1","md5":"f821140dd1450d9a68696a19cd18821c","shkey":"eJf7XbaPJsG3orhGnToxemxJeWzyF3EC5
eAq7Npqk=","t":"How to pick up a \ue000cat\ue001 like a pro - Vet advice on \ue000cat\ue001 ...","mid":"
AD782D503E4D9CA0CB8E78856E5ACBE21B07DE","desc":"cat vet advice handling pick"}', '{"cid":"i7j33APQ","pur
:"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat","murl":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4b/D
estic_Cat_Demonstrating_Dilated_Slit_Pupils.jpg/220px-Domestic_Cat_Demonstrating_Dilated_Slit_Pupils.jpg
"turl":"https://tse3.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.i7j33APQBvtlAYmJErPMhwAAAA&pid=15.1","md5":"8bb8f7dc03d006fb6
1898912b3cc87","shkey":"S3GTy2277E+KqJenmAcVhv6Ly7MfcU3XGbC1JAnHcO4=","t":"\ue000Cat\ue001 - Wikipedia",
id":"2B47BE55BDEDC04E0016DB8A5CDAB14D8CBE09A9","desc":"cat domestic dilated pupils wikipedia wiki slit w
ipediam"}', '{"cid":"+HbjTmpW","purl":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1TMEaKyE8pw","murl":"https://i.yt
g.com/vi/1TMEaKyE8pw/hqdefault.jpg","turl":"https://tse1.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.-HbjTmpWh0U7pBqnKxF2kQHaF
pid=15.1","md5":"f876e34e6a5687453ba41aa72b117691","shkey":"pdhXF7rFvEa2XxSjRk88q9Ef/2lgtwhlPmZRyTLhZKE=
"t":"Funny \ue000Cat\ue001 Bath 2013 - YouTube","mid":"A915348859EBF5E9DE540831ADF243181D363EC3","desc":
at bath funny"}', '{"cid":"mnvcW4H+","purl":"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ze8OmH_Zvlg","murl":"https:/
.ytimg.com/vi/ze8OmH_Zvlg/hqdefault.jpg","turl":"https://tse4.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.mnvcW4H-cqNVDLHmFlk7
HaFj&pid=15.1","md5":"9a7bdc5b81fe72a3550cb1e616593ba4","shkey":"/PLG95xACMCkubeFIv84yVFjBBcwAFyyQSkEJCO
xU=","t":"Munchkin \ue000Cat\ue001 Grooming Himself - YouTube","mid":"8BACF37B56EEF11DCCED8D5BBE9FC0077E
E4AC","desc":"cat munchkin grooming himself"}', '{"cid":"XULI4Paj","purl":"https://www.youtube.com/watch
=_NndSy2JR3c","murl":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/_NndSy2JR3c/maxresdefault.jpg","turl":"https://tse4.mm.bing
et/th?id=OIP.XULI4PajCI9VA48rj-O-UQHaEK&pid=15.1","md5":"5d42c8e0f6a3088f55038f2b8fe3be51","shkey":"q+XL
Sg/+XNn6xxPFVqNqx605W6/GnGatYTEbzP+dU=","t":"THE WOLF \ue000CAT\ue001 - The Lykoi - YouTube","mid":"97B4
9B549E6E80A7E67C867DDC5AD39AA9A5B8","desc":"lykoi cat wolf breed werewolf guy werewolves dodo hated scoo
r turns dad ultimate special animal"}', '{"cid":"prhbPpvf","purl":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somali_
t","murl":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c6/Blue_Somali_kitten_age_3_months.jpg
200px-Blue_Somali_kitten_age_3_months.jpg","turl":"https://tse3.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.prhbPpvfN4tlsqnheW
mQHaFj&pid=15.1","md5":"a6b85b3e9bdf378b65b2a9e179646199","shkey":"BT0hxF/DerB1g4mL7o6M2/KTGDBy6HiqCYh9w
47Gc=","t":"Somali \ue000cat\ue001 - Wikipedia","mid":"C7F9F1321500598998BDBA40C7C402E40752500A","desc":
omali wikipedia cat kitten wiki months"}', '{"cid":"o8LbSVIj","purl":"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siam
e_cat","murl":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f6/Siamese_Cat_p.jpg/1200px-Siames
Cat_p.jpg","turl":"https://tse4.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.o8LbSVIjkCNCPEXeuvSu1gHaHl&pid=15.1","md5":"a3c2db
52239023423c45debaf4aed6","shkey":"NsZXfm7H/WsyPG7xZi7JS1eh3ZGqYjiCiClE/2IHbFI=","t":"Siamese \ue000cat\
001 - Wikipedia","mid":"1C5812CF7F9D820F828C775F7A182485E6E790FF","desc":"siamese cat wikipedia wiki"}']

for x in range(len(urls)):
    print(ast.literal_eval(urls[x]).get('murl'))
```

Comment: Если у вас данные приходят с какого-то сервиса, то это json, а не словарь, поэтому нужно использовать json.loads

Comment: Нет, это не json.
Парсер изображений

Comment: Что парсер изображений? Кстати, код из ответа не запустится из-за множественных синтаксических ошибок (даже если объединить список в одну строку, все равно некоторые символы отсутствуют - буквы, слеши в адресах, кавычки, запятые).

Comment: Парсер изображений из Bing. Не знаю почему не запускается, у меня все отлично ( возможно потому что я скопировал лишь часть, и оно обрезалось криво )

Comment: Хм нет, действительно строка вся в ошибках

Comment: Тогда извините, но в любом случае проблему я решил